# matlab-how to separate one row one column of a large binary number into many columns, one per entry

Tags: matlab

So I am trying to send a jpeg through a binary symmetric channel (bsc) matlab has a function for this but it requires the information be in one row and all separated entries.

For example:
this is what i have- 01010101 (1x1) and this is what i need 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 (1x8)

I've tried reshape and a lot of other things but no dice. any help would be appreciated.
~kelly

Comment: `input_binary_string - '0'`?

Comment: Thank you! Perfect! What topic in help would I find this? I searched so much. :)

Comment: Well it converts the input into a numeric array by subtracting the decimal value of the character `0` which is 48 from it. This acts as the "basline" for any character to numeric equivalent conversion.